# Как изменить цвет границы QLineEdit когда он выбран?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qss, qlineedit

Питон не выдает никаких ошибок, но этот стиль не применяется, не работает, когда `QLineEdit` выбран:

```
each.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_MacShowFocusRect, 0)
each.setStyleSheet('''
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: rgb(206, 214, 224);

    QLineEdit: focused {
        border-color: rgb(61, 156, 255);
    }
''')
```

Comment: Вопрос, вероятно, будет закрыт, так как на Stack Overflow на русском вопросы принято задавать **только на русском языке**. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или воспользуйтесь Stack Overflow на английском.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обратите внимание не `QLineEdit:focused`, а `QLineEdit:focus`

Пробуйте так:

```
from PyQt5.Qt import *

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.textEdit = QTextEdit(placeholderText="Это - TextEdit")
        self.textEdit.placeholderText = "Hello World" 

        self.lineEdit = QLineEdit(placeholderText="Смените focus на TextEdit")       

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        layout.addWidget(self.textEdit)


StyleSheet = '''
    QLineEdit {
        border-width: 3px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: rgb(0, 214, 255);
    }
    QLineEdit:focus {
        border-color: rgb(255, 156, 0);
    }
'''

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(StyleSheet)                       # + 

    default_font = QFont()
    default_font.setPointSize(16)
    app.setFont(default_font)
    w = Window() 
    w.resize(600, 300)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спасибо огромное